# Visual Studio 2015 shortcut for publishing web.config

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

How can I publish the web.config file only and not the entire project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your web.config file in solution explorer and press `Alt + ¨, Alt + P`.

This actually works for any selected file(s) in solution explorer.